# How to disable soft deletes in Laravel 5.8 Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, oop, laravel-5, eloquent, soft-delete

On my project all models extend `BaseModel` class, which uses `SoftDeletes` trait by default. But in some specific cases, e.g. in class `ShouldHardDelete` I don't want my DB records to be deleted softly. Let's suppose, I can't deny extending `BaseModel`.

What changes should I make in my `ShouldHardDelete` class to prevent it from using soft deletes?

Comment: out of curiosity why would you want to completely remove record?

Comment: @usrNotFound, I will have to insert and delete multiple records (can't simply change them, too complex logic). Soft-deletes are not so necessary for these records, keeping deleted ones in DB would cause too much disk space wasted

Comment: I think `$modal->forceDelete()` and would the job

Comment: That's an option, but that would make me do some exceptional processing if I ever want to delete these objects along with some other soft-deletable ones

Answer (score 8):

There are two things you should do:

1. There is a static method `bootSoftDeletes()` in `SoftDeletes` trait, which initializes soft-delete behaviour for the model:

```php
    /**
     * Boot the soft deleting trait for a model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function bootSoftDeletes()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new SoftDeletingScope);
    }
```

Override it in the `ShouldHardDelete` class to an empty method:

```php
    /**
     * Disable soft deletes for this model
     */
    public static function bootSoftDeletes() {}
```

2. Set `$forceDeleting` field to `true` in `ShouldHardDelete`:

```php
    protected $forceDeleting = true;
```

Thus, you can disable soft-deleting behaviour, while still extending `BaseModel` which uses `SoftDeletes` trait.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `softDelete` trait but don't want to use it on a specific query then you can do using the `withoutGlobalScope` method in the model.

```
User::withoutGlobalScope(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope::class)->get();
```

if you want to use multiple models for a specific query then better to extends eloquent builder in `AppServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
{
   Builder::macro('withoutSoftDeletingScope', function () {
     $this->withoutGlobalScope(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope::class);

       return $this;
    });
 }
```

and then you can call as a method in any model

```
User::withoutSoftDeletingScope()->get();
```